# Install Opencv on mac

Tags: python, terminal, anaconda

When I try to install opencv throw anaconda in terminal I get the following problem:

[image: error in terminal]

how do I fix this problem?

Comment: `conda install -c conda-forge opencv `

Comment: Please do not post error messages or code in images; search engines cannot index them, so no one else can find your post to help future users with this same problem, and blind users cannot read the post at all.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try:

```
pip3 install opencv-python
```

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV definitely works with python3.

But http://cyaninfinite.com/tutorials/installing-opencv-in-ubuntu-for-python-3/ suggests that the packaging situation is not straightforward, as some platforms are better supported than others.

It looks like you're encountering a package that was only intended for python2, hence the conflict. You may be facing a "build from source" situation here.